# How I can return back old "Window Present" effect from KDE 2.24.X in KDE 2.25.X?

Tags: linux, kde-plasma

I very like KDE, but this new effect is bad(not smooth like old effect), how I can do this?

Edit

[Present window from KDE 5.24.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uuYNp.png)

[Present window from KDE 5.25.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MalQ.png)

Comment: This question belongs on https://superuser.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com rather than here. If you do ask on one of those, it would be a good idea to include a bit more description of what "old" and "new" effect you are talking about.

Comment: Also, do you mean 5.25 rather than 2.25?